# How to arrange the settings.STATIC_ROOT to point towards the correct path?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am trying to add CSS styling to my html email to be sent so I used `django-inlinecss 0.3.0`

In my template I am using the following:

```
{% load inlinecss %}
{% inlinecss "/css/bootstrap.css" %}
TEXT
{% endinlinecss %}
```

Here is the complete path of the CSS file:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Project\static_in_env\css\bootstrap.css
```

I have tried the following:

```
{% inlinecss static "css/bootstrap.css" %}
```

After debugging I found that the reason is due to

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\static_root\\css\\bootstrap.css'
```

Here is the files structure:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

So, how should I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

**1) setting.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR/"static/", ]
```

**2) urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**3) Create Static Folder**

create a static folder inside startproject (project_name).

The Folder name should be ***"static"***

**4) Add your css file**

Inside that **static** folder create a **"css"** folder and then add your css file (bootstrap.css)

Once you done all the setup for static file, now we can work with html template.

**5) Html Template**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Custom Css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" />
</head>
</html>
```